# ImportError: cannot import name 'get_avg_size' from 'utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/utils/__init__.py)

Tags: tensorflow, importerror

Import is failing when the following code is run:
#import MobileNetV2
from scipy.sparse import base
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense,Input,GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras import activations
from utils import get_avg_size,split_data
import os